# Gracenote Entourage Movie Lookup

Tags: gracenote

I am using the Gracenote Entourage SDK for iOS and am able to recognize Live TV shows however when I try to recognize a Movie either from DVD or VOD it returns no matches.  I have signed up for the Accelerator program which should give me access to the full database rather than the last seven days of aired broadcasts.

Can anyone provide an example returning movie data?  Should I have access to this data with the Accelerator Plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accelerator program gives you access to publicly available API's for commercial use. However, recognizing DVD or VOD is currently available to enterprise customers only.